# IIS 8.5 Error while performing operation on web.config

Tags: iis, iis-8.5, web.config

I have a test server and a prod server that host a `.netcore2.1` website. On the test server, I can access to the website and publish with MSDeploy without any problem.

On the prod server I can publish correctly from Visual Studio, everything is setting like on the test server but I have this when I try to open the website:

```
Http Error 500.19
Error Code    0x8007000d
Config File   \\?\C:\MySite\web.config
```

I have the same configuration on both server, same version of program, web deploy 3.6 and URL rewrite installed.

The only visible difference is in the **Services** where the **Web deployement agent Service** is not listed on the prod server. However I had checked it in the Webdeploy install process.

**Interesting thing**: When I publish with the *"Self-contained"* option, the website is displayable so I suspect a missing thing but I don't find what.

I tried a lot of thing by searching on forum and microsoft documentation but nothing solve this problem.

Comment: A .NET Framework web site shouldn't have a "self contained" publish option. So what exactly are you publishing? Besides, 500.19 with 0x8007000d almost always points to missing OOB components https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/oob-500.html

Comment: @LexLi, Sorry it is a .NetCore 2.1 website, my bad.

Comment: Then the most likely cause is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034308/asp-net-core-web-api-published-in-iis-after-moved-to-different-iis-server-pc-giv

Comment: @LexLi, the hosting bundle was already installed, but I just uninstall and install again and now it's working, weird but solved

Comment: You are not the first, and not the last, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54984884/error-500-19-with-0x8007000d-when-running-asp-net-core-app-in-iis-despite-aspnet

Comment: Indeed, thank you for the help, IIS is very capricious

Answer (score 0):

I had exact the same issue with a CyberArk website (on IIS10) for load balancer monitor service.
After installing the website, a repair of the MS .NET Core 3.1.22 Bundle solved the issue